# Secure WCF binding in a Portable class library with Xamarin

Tags: c#, wcf, binding, xamarin, portable-class-library

I have a WCF service that has a `WSHttpBinding`. Unfortunately in my PCL for some reason I cannot use `WSHttpBinding`. I can only use `BasicHttpBinding`. Is there a way that I can use a secure binding in a portable class library? I am using Xamarin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx) I read about transport security:

> Transport Security
>
> When using transport security, the user credentials
> and claims are passed by using the transport layer. In other words,
> user credentials are transport-dependent, which allows fewer
> authentication options compared to message security. Each transport
> protocol (TCP, IPC, MSMQ, or HTTP) has its own mechanism for passing
> credentials and handling message protection. The most common approach
> for this is to use Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) for encrypting and
> signing the contents of the packets sent over Secure HTTP (HTTPS).
> Transport security is used to provide point-to-point security between
> the two endpoints (service and client). If there are intermediary
> systems between client and the service, each intermediate point must
> forward the message over a new SSL connection.

I concluded that a secure binding **for PCL would be:**

```
 BasicHttpBinding bind= new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
```

**Web.config Binding:**

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicSecure">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```