# Connect xamarin with HTTPS WCF service( WShttpbinding with a security mod MessageWithtransport)

Tags: c#, ios, wcf, xamarin

We have an existing Soap HTTPS WCF service with WShttpBinding with a security mode of TransportWithMessageCredentials.Can I consume this WCF service inside my IOS Xamarin application? I already consumed basichttpbinding WCF service after created the proxy of the WCF service inside the Ios application.Can Anyone tell me how to consume the HTTPS WShttpBinding binding WCF service to my Xamarin application?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the exact same challenge.

Comment: I think, There is no direct way to use WShttpBinding  with Xamarin.I have used HttpBinding  with a security mode "Transport".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot use `WSHttpBinding`:

[From this Question I would use:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284533/secure-wcf-binding-in-a-portable-class-library-with-xamarin/25409457#25409457)

**PCL:**

```
 BasicHttpBinding bind= new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
```

**Web.config Binding:**

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicSecure">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```